# Python pandas group by, transform multiple columns with custom conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have dataframe containing 500k+ records and I would like to group-by multiple columns (data type of string and date) and later pick only few records inside each group based on custom condition.

Basically, I need to group the records (by `first_roll_up`, `date`, `granular_timestamp`) to check if the group contains any value for column `top` and if present, choose only the record with `top` value. Also, if the group doesn't contain any record with `top` value, choose all the records.

Input:

| first_roll_up | sub | top | date | granular_timestamp | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  | T1 | 2/10/2022 | 2/10/2022 10:00:00:000 | . |
| ABC | SUB_A_1 |  | 2/10/2022 | 2/10/2022 10:00:00:000 | . |
| ABC | SUB_A_2 |  | 2/10/2022 | 2/10/2022 10:00:00:000 | . |
| ABC | SUB_A_3 |  | 2/10/2022 | 2/10/2022 10:00:00:000 | . |
| XYZ | SUB_X_1 |  | 2/12/2022 | 2/10/2022 11:00:00:000 | . |
| XYZ | SUB_X_2 |  | 2/12/2022 | 2/10/2022 11:00:00:000 | . |
| XYZ | SUB_Y_1 |  | 2/12/2022 | 2/10/2022 12:00:00:000 | . |

Output:

| first_roll_up | sub | top | date | granular_timestamp | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC |  | T1 | 2/10/2022 | 2/10/2022 10:00:00:000 | . |
| XYZ | SUB_X_1 |  | 2/12/2022 | 2/10/2022 11:00:00:000 | . |
| XYZ | SUB_X_2 |  | 2/12/2022 | 2/10/2022 11:00:00:000 | . |
| XYZ | SUB_Y_1 |  | 2/12/2022 | 2/10/2022 12:00:00:000 | . |

I tried to perform the below, but the function is taking 10+ mins to complete. I tried `transform` instead of apply by adding new boolean column to identify groups, but it didn't help too.

```
df.groupby(['first_roll_up', 'sub', 'top', 'date', 'granular_timestamp'], sort=False)
        .apply(custom_function_to_filter_each_group_records)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need to use `groupby()` at all here, but rather some filtering and concatenating.

First, we'll create a dataframe which helps us identify whether a row has a `top` value of `T1`.

```
df_t1 = df[df['top'] == 'T1']
```

We now want to find all rows that do *not* contain any value of `T1` and join it by `first_roll_up`. This seems to only occur when `sub` is missing, which makes your data appear to be hierarchical (e.g. `first_roll_up` --> `sub`).

```
df_want = pd.merge(df, df_t1, on='first_roll_up', how='outer', indicator=True, suffixes=('', '_drop')) \
            .query("_merge == 'left_only'") \
            .drop(columns='_merge')
```

This gives us a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  first_roll_up      sub  top  ... date_drop granular_timestamp_drop values_drop
4           XYZ  SUB_X_1       ...       NaN                     NaN         NaN
5           XYZ  SUB_X_2       ...       NaN                     NaN         NaN
6           XYZ  SUB_Y_1       ...       NaN                     NaN         NaN
```

Because of the way we joined, we have a set of columns that we don't care about. We've suffixed them with `_drop`. We'll remove these later.

Now we'll just stack our values of `T1` on top of the dataframe we just created and drop the columns we don't want:

```
df_want = pd.concat([df_t1, df_want.loc[:, ~df_want.columns.str.endswith('_drop')]], ignore_index=True)
```

Final output:

```
  first_roll_up      sub top       date      granular_timestamp values
0           ABC           T1  2/10/2022  2/10/2022 10:00:00:000      .
1           XYZ  SUB_X_1      2/12/2022  2/10/2022 11:00:00:000      .
2           XYZ  SUB_X_2      2/12/2022  2/10/2022 11:00:00:000      .
3           XYZ  SUB_Y_1      2/12/2022  2/10/2022 12:00:00:000      .
```

Comment: We are merging the data on "first_roll_up". Would it work for the case where we have more records with `top` value but with same "first_roll_up". Basically the logic would be applied on a group (within given "first_roll_up", "date", "granular_timestamp"). I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.groupby(['first_roll_up', 'date', 'granular_timestamp'], as_index=False)
.apply(lambda g: g if g.top.isna().all() else g.loc[g.top.notna()])
.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
  first_roll_up       sub  top        date       granular_timestamp values
0          ABC        NaN  T1   2/10/2022   2/10/2022 10:00:00:000       .
1          XYZ   SUB_X_1   NaN  2/12/2022   2/10/2022 11:00:00:000       .
2          XYZ   SUB_X_2   NaN  2/12/2022   2/10/2022 11:00:00:000       .
3          XYZ   SUB_Y_1   NaN  2/12/2022   2/10/2022 12:00:00:000       .
```